# Does anyone know what tool or ways to create this multi-colored dither effect?

Tags: color, halftone

I'm curious what tools or process you need to not only create this nice dither/dot pattern but to make it with multicolored like the example below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: looks just like noise, what tool are you using?

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be simply the **Noise** filter in **Photoshop**.

`Filter > Noise > Add Noise...`

[image]

Comment: with a little bit of masking

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a tool, I'd like to suggest GIMP because it's free, Open Source, and cross-platform. You could also do the same in Photoshop (but it's not free).

Create your artwork in GIMP (or Photshop) using as many layers as you want. I used the Pen tool to create nice smooth selections, and filled them with basic flat colours. Using a large soft edge brush set to low opacity, set the alpha lock (Photoshop: transparency lock) on each layer,  and paint in some nice colour gradients, then finally add a 50% grey filled layer at the top, and do *Filters > Noise > RGB Noise* (Photoshop: *Filter > Add noise*, uncheck "monochromatic").

Set the layer blending mode of the RGB noise layer to *Overlay*

Example

[image]